# Generate list of numbers whose GCD is given

Tags: algorithm, math, greatest-common-divisor

I have been given 2 numbers say G & n. Find all possible list of n numbers [A0, A1, A2, ....... Ai, ....., Aj... An] whose gcd is G following the below constraints:

- GCD ( A0, A1, A2, .... ,Ai, ..... ,An-1 ) = G.
- Ai > G, ∀ 0 ≤ i < n.
- Ai ≥ Aj, ∀ j ≤ i

  Define a function, sum(A) = A0 + A1 + .... + An-1.
  If multiple sequences satisfy first three properties, print the one which minimizes sum(A) function.

Example: G = 4, N = 3. So a possible list of numbers: [8, 12, 20].

My approach: I generate a list of n prime numbers and printed G*prime[j] for all 0 <= j < n. But that doesn't seem to be working.

```
public class GeneratingSequence {

    private static int MAX = 1000;
    private static int MAX1 = 8000;

    private void sieve(int[] a)
    {
        boolean[] b = new boolean[MAX1];
        int aIndex = 0;

        for(int i = 1; i < MAX1; i++)
        {
            if(!b[i])
            {
                //System.out.print((i + 1) + " ");

                if(aIndex < a.length)
                    a[aIndex++] = i + 1;

                markMultiples(i + 1, b);
            }
        }
    }

    private void markMultiples(int n, boolean[] b)
    {
        int i = 2, num;

        while((num = i * n) <= MAX1)
        {
            b[num - 1] = true;
            i++;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException
    {
        GeneratingSequence gs = new GeneratingSequence();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int[] primes = new int[MAX];

        gs.sieve(primes);

        int T = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        for(int i = 0; i < T; i++)
        {
            String[] a = br.readLine().split("\\s");
            long g = Long.parseLong(a[0]);
            int n = Integer.parseInt(a[1]);

            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                long t = g*primes[j];
                System.out.print(t + " ");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us that you've tried to do your own homework, and where you got stuck.

Comment: hey @robmayoff - Please look at the edits and suggest solution.

Comment: Are you *sure* that's the task? because unless I'm missing something, GCD( 2*G , 3*G , 4*G, 5*G, ... (n+1)*G ) = G, and that's too simple, can be solved analytically.

Comment: Am I right that [2G, 3G, 3G, 3G, ...] would be a valid sequence for any n?

Comment: @Henry - see 3rd constraint, but almost like my comment.

Comment: @Amit third constrains just says >=, so repeating values should be ok

Comment: @Henry - Ahh! didn't even notice the *equals* in there :-) so obviously something is wrong in the question.

Comment: @Amit  ... In the result list the the GCD should be G. So how just generating 2G, 3G, 4G can help? And also there may be many possible list. You have to generate that list which generates the least sum of its elements. What about that?

Comment: GCD of that list ***is*** G, but as Henry noted, it's even simpler then that. Make sure you got the question right.

Comment: @Amit the question is right

Comment: Then @Henry has the right answer, and *[8, 12, 20]* is not (Try it, *GCD(8, 12, 12)*)

Comment: No, though the condition says Ai ≥ Aj, ∀ j ≤ i, all possible Ai & Aj are to be considered. Otherwise there is no meaning of the question. Forget the '=' though it is there I know.

Comment: If you make the third condition stronger Ai > Aj, ∀ j < i, then @Amit has the correct answer; However, then the question is NOT right.

Comment: Well I still have not got the correct answer. Test cases are failing.

Comment: This is question from ongoing contest https://www.hackerearth.com/zomato-hiring-challenge/problems/312bb6c750484dbbb929c9a97c177a91/

Comment: @Henry Why [2*G, 3*G, 3*G...]. Shouldn't it be [2*G, 2*G, 2*G...] It satisfy both 2nd and 3rd requirements ai >= aj for all j<i and aj > g. (This is an ongoing contest so you can answer after this https://www.hackerearth.com/zomato-hiring-challenge/ ends. )

Comment: @Death-Stalker: The gcd of [2G, 2G, ..., 2G] is 2G, not G. However, even better than Henry's answer is [3G, 2G, 2G, ..., 2G].

Comment: @JamesKPolk except that it violates constraint 3

Answer (score 3):

The first constraint tells us that all A have to be integer multiples of G, lets say A<sub>i</sub> = F<sub>i</sub>*G and that the gcd of the F<sub>i</sub> must be 1.

From the second constraint we know that F<sub>i</sub> >= 2.

The third constraint says the sequence must be non-decreasing.

A sequence that fulfills all three constraints is:

[2*G, 2*G, 2*G, ..., 2*G, 3*G]

and this sequence also has the smallest sum.